# python parallel calculations in a while loop

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I have been looking around for some time, but haven't had luck finding an example that could solve my problem. I have added an example from my code. As one can notice this is slow and the 2 functions could be done separately.

My aim is to print every second the latest parameter values. At the same time the slow processes can be calculated in the background. The latest value is shown and when any process is ready the value is updated.

Can anybody recommend a better way to do it? An example would be really helpful.

Thanks a lot.

```
import time

def ProcessA(parA):
    # imitate slow process
    time.sleep(5)
    parA += 2

    return parA

def ProcessB(parB):
    # imitate slow process
    time.sleep(10)
    parB += 5

    return parB

# start from here
i, parA, parB = 1, 0, 0

while True: # endless loop
    print(i)
    print(parA)
    print(parB)

    time.sleep(1)
    i += 1

    # update parameter A
    parA = ProcessA(parA)

    # update parameter B
    parB = ProcessB(parB)
```

Comment: The most direct way is probably to use threads. Have a look at the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#module-threading) module.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this should do it for you. This has the benefit of you being able to add extra parallel funcitons up to a total equal to the number of cores you have. Edits are welcome.

```
#import time module
import time

#import the appropriate multiprocessing functions
from multiprocessing import Pool

#define your functions
#whatever your slow function is
def slowFunction(x):
    return someFunction(x)

#printingFunction
def printingFunction(new,current,timeDelay):
    while new == current:
        print current
        time.sleep(timeDelay)


#set the initial value that will be printed.
#Depending on your function this may take some time. 
CurrentValue = slowFunction(someTemporallyDynamicVairable)

#establish your pool
pool = Pool()

while True: #endless loop

    #an asynchronous function, this will continue
    # to run in the background while your printing operates.
    NewValue = pool.apply_async(slowFunction(someTemporallyDynamicVairable))

    pool.apply(printingFunction(NewValue,CurrentValue,1))

    CurrentValue = NewValue

#close your pool
pool.close()
```